# Printing Android Advertising ID in a Textview

Tags: java, android

**Problem:** 
  I am trying to write a barebones android application that just shows your advertising ID in a textview. My code compiles fine but when I run it my textview remains unchanged (it just remains as "New Text").

[This is a picture of the screen I'm getting on both my AVD and Actual Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN1V1.jpg)

**My Code:** 
I have already imported the google play services SDK and am using this following code within the onCreate method which is within the MainActivity class.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //The textview I am trying to change
    uniqueID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.special);
    // declarations for included ad plugin 
    adtechView = (AdtechBannerView) findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
    adtechView.getAdConfiguration();

    Context mContext = MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext();

    try {
        //This should be getting the advertising ID

        AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);
        String AdId = adInfo.getId();

        //This should change the textview "uniqueID" to the Ad ID
        uniqueID.setText("Your ID is " + AdId);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**What I've tried:**

I have looked into the problem through some of related questions. multiple sources say that the code might not work due to not having access to google play services.

I have tried running the code both on my AVD which does not have google play services and on my actual device which does. Both end up with the same result. (textview remains unchanged)

I have written this code based on this website: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/01/16/advertising-id-android-kitkat/
which provides a tutorial for retrieving the Ad-ID.

I have also used this stack overflow as guide, but I am not face with the same issue his code was facing:
[AdvertisingIdClient getAdvertisingIdInfo hangs forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379879/advertisingidclient-getadvertisingidinfo-hangs-forever)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the Advertiser ID from the main thread.  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/01/16/advertising-id-android-kitkat/

From the code above, it appears that this is taking place on the main thread.  I'd recommend using an AsyncTask. Put the advertising ID in the doInBackground implementation. Since you can only modify UI on the main thread, set the text of the TextView in the onPostExecute implementation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I have put my code inside AsyncTask, and have followed as you instructed. I set the return type of my doInBackground to a string, and passed it to onPostExecute to set the text. However my String AdId is always null. Due to the char limit I have attached a screen shot of my Asynctask: http://i.imgur.com/tHGjEir.png Thanks once again!

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar with AsyncTask you are.  Did you start the task properly by calling -- adIdTask.execute()?  If you call the doInBackground method directly it won't work properly.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I call my AsyncTask function inside my "on resume" part of my main activity with AsyncCaller().execute(): http://i.imgur.com/r4vChne.png 
I looked up an AsyncTask tutorial on Stackoverflow. 

Just in case you need it here is my full code:
https://codeshare.io/0SZJP 
Thanks once again!

Comment: And there are no stack traces coming up? If there are any, you should post them.  Have you tried just printing the AdId to LogCat?

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I copy pasted this into a fresh project with google play services and it worked fine. i removed the AdTechView, but otherwise it's the same. One thing to note is that you never hide your loading dialog in the post execute.  But I think I know the real problem that you're facing.  Are you testing on an emulator? Emulators don't have advertising ids, and when I test mine on an emulated device the ID is null.

Comment: Thanks for being so attentive with my inquiry; I really appreciate it. Yes I have been testing it on my AVD, I've also tried it on my actual device. How did you test yours to get it working? I've looked at the logs/stack which tell me that google play services isn't available which is strange because I remember installing the play services sdk components and including the necessary dependancy. My codes an absolute mess at the moment, but I'll  make a new project and start over the see if it works. I checked my AVD under google settings -> Ads and oddly there's an Ad ID.

Comment: Update: I finally got my code working, i think it was a problem in the gradle file and how i set up the play services